# PHP Integer Configuration (e.g. 1=apache,2=php,3=apache+php)

Tags: php, configuration, integer

How can I parse a configuration value with PHP which is a number and a total of other numbers.

One example of this is:

1 -> Logging Enabled
2 -> Error Reporting Enabled
4 -> E-Mail Reporting Enabled

3 -> Logging + Error Enabled
5 -> Logging + E-Mail Enabled

Comment: question is not clear to me. Here 5->1+4 as your example. But 5->3+2 is also possible. Is there any way to separate combined and single configuration option/value?

Comment: @Sadat: The second row of numbers is sums of the numbers in the first row, partly as examples.  How to separate the values, i believe, is what he was asking in the first place.

Comment: Sums won't work because of what @Sadat explained. @cHao 's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't just have a sum -- you have yourself a set of flags, or a bit field, with each flag represented by one bit.

```
$logging     = !!($cfgval & 1);
$errorReport = !!($cfgval & 2);
$emailReport = !!($cfgval & 4);
```

The "!!" just ensures that numbers that aren't 0 (ie: numbers with the specific bit set) end up as the same "true" value that the rest of PHP uses, so stuff like `($logging == true)` always works as expected.  It's not required, but i highly recommend you convert the value to a boolean somehow; `(bool)` would work as well, even if it is 3 times as many characters.  :)

As long as you keep the numbers as powers of two (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32...), it's easy to extend this up to 31-32 different flags (integers are 32 bits in size, but the top bit is a sign bit which acts kinda funny if you don't know about "two's complement" math).

Comment: do u think, that one will put a configuration key/value like 1024, 2048, ..., 16384, ... so on? is it handy or feasible? i dont think so.

Comment: @Sadat: sure.  Define constants for the values, and it's extremely easy to work with.  Not so easy for a human to put into a config file, but that's something a decent setup/install page could whip up in no time.  Or you could use hex numbers, where 4 bits == 1 digit, and it gets a lot easier even for humans.

Comment: Why should `!!` be better than `(bool)`?

Comment: It'd work the same, i imagine.  `!!` is shorter, though, and makes just as much sense to me.